# A set of real numbers is said to be a $G_\delta$ set provided it is a intersection of a countable collection of open sets...

Tags: real-analysis

> A set of real numbers is said to be a $G_\delta$ set provided it is a intersection of a countable collection of open sets. Show that for any bounded set E, there is a $G_\delta$ set G for which $$E\subset G$$ and $$m^*(G)=m^*(E)$$ ($m^*$ is called outer measure, that is to say: Consider a subset of real number $A$, and the set of all countable collections of nonempty open, bounded intervals that cover A, let's call it F. The sums of the lengths of all intervals in a set from family F form a set B. m*A is defined to the infimum of the set B)

My idea is that for every bounded set $E$, there should exist a countable collection of open sets, whose intersection equals to this set. If that is the case, then let the intersection be $G$, then $G$ is a $G_\delta$ set, and the statements would hold. But I don't know how to prove my little theorem, since I have to take into account too many cases. Maybe what I think is wrong and I'm just not being aware of something essential.

Comment: How do you define $m^*$?

Comment: Your idea won’t work, I’m afraid: there $2^\mathfrak{c}$ bounded subsets of $\Bbb R$ but only $\mathfrak{c}$ $G_\delta$ sets.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott how do you know there are $2^c$ bounded subsets of R and c $G_\sigma$ sets?

Comment: @pxc3110 There are already $2^{|[0,1]|}=2^{\mathfrak c}$ subsets of $[0,1]$. - Each open set is the countable union of rational-ended open intervals, hence $G_\delta$ sets are describable by countably times countably many pairs of rationals; that's $\mathfrak c$ many.

Comment: An obviuos choice of $G$, if $M$ is an absolute bound for $E$ (i.e. $|x|<M$ for all $x\in E$, would be $G=(-M,M)$. But that has $m^*=2M$, whereas $m^*(E)$ may be smaller. Can you find *any* decent improvement for the choice of $G$? Can you find a sequence o fbetter and better improvements?

Comment: @pxc3110: Every subset of $(0,1)$ is bounded, and since $(0,1)$ has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$, it has $2^\mathfrak{c}$ subsets. There are only $\mathfrak{c}=2^\omega$ open sets, however, since $\Bbb R$ has a countable base. Each $G_\delta$ comes from a sequence of open sets, and there are $$\mathfrak{c}^\omega=(2^\omega)^\omega$=2^{\omega\cdot\omega}=2^{\omega}= \mathfrak{c}$$ sequences of open sets, so there are at most (and in fact exactly) $\mathfrak{c}$ $G_\delta$ sets.

Comment: By the way, what you’ve been calling $G_\sigma$ sets are actually $G_\delta$ sets; I’ve corrected this in your question.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks :)

Comment: The set $E=\mathbb Q\cap(0,1)$ of rational numbers between $0$ and $1$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb R$ but is not a $G_\delta$ set.

Comment: You should use that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an open $U$ with $E\subset U$ and $m^\ast(U) < m^\ast(E) + \varepsilon$.